# error array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array, integer given

Tags: php

I am getting error in a php ticket system ;

> array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array, integer given
> The following error occured:
> array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array, integer given in domain..../core/helpers/ProjectActions.php, line 73

and lines are from 73 to 80;

```
 $k = array_search($issue->getID(), $_SESSION['viewissue_list']);
    if ($k !== false)
    unset($_SESSION['viewissue_list'][$k]);
     array_push($_SESSION['viewissue_list'], $issue->getID());

            if (count($_SESSION['viewissue_list']) > 10)
                array_shift($_SESSION['viewissue_list']);
```

This problem began wo making any change at code.
any idea ?

Comment: What is the output for `var_dump($_SESSION['viewissue_list']);`? (append to the question)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that, `$_SESSION['viewissue_list']` doesn’t have any value. Maybe, user visit site first time. You can check it before search any value in session such:

```php
$k = array_search($issue->getID(), ($_SESSION['viewissue_list']?:[]));
    if ($k !== false)
    unset($_SESSION['viewissue_list'][$k]);
     array_push($_SESSION['viewissue_list'], $issue->getID());
 if(count($_SESSION['viewissue_list']) > 10)
                array_shift($_SESSION['viewissue_list']);
```

Comment: Yes. Probably when you set value to $_SESSION['viewissue_list'] sometimes you put there null/false or you do not set it.